# Powershell - Need a way to extract the attachments from .eml file

Tags: powershell, foreach, email-attachments, eml

I have written the below Powershell code that loops through all attachments in a given ".eml" file.
My goal is to be able to extract each attachment to a local directory.

Up to now, I have been able to only print the filenames (to see that the loop indeed accesses the attachments).

Thank you in advance.

```
$emlFn  = "thedirectory\file.eml"
$adoDbStream = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Stream
$adoDbStream.Open()
$adoDbStream.LoadFromFile($emlFn)
$cdoMessage = New-Object -ComObject CDO.Message
$cdoMessage.DataSource.OpenObject($adoDbStream, "_Stream")

foreach($attachment in $cdoMessage.Attachments){
    Write-Output $attachment.FileName

    #I need some code here to save each attachment locally

}

$adoDbStream.Close()
```

Comment: Try `$attachment.SaveToFile("$(Join-Path $PWD $attachment.FileName)")`

Comment: Thank you very much Mathias, it worked perfectly.
Note for the other users: $pwd can be an existing destination path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Exchange Server 2003 SDK docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2003/aa487389(v=exchg.65)) the interface used for attachments expose a `SaveToFile` method - pass the full path to it to save the attachment to disk:

```
# construct output path from current directory + attachment filename
$exportPath = Join-Path $PWD $attachment.FileName

# save to disk
$attachment.SaveToFile("$exportPath")
```